# Apps Script webhooks and Access-Control-Allow-Origin header missing

Tags: google-apps-script, htmx

I have a Google Apps Script project acting as a webhook. When calling the endpoint using a library like [htmx](https://htmx.org), the preflight check fails and the request subsequently fails. When calling directly with `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`, it works fine.

[I have a sample endpoint](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxeEcsxk6MO3FD4RxPEIpvWxo-dM-YQcmJ5yOdWFoKNe9nxC3jHbMx4DxI6Xghb6DhZwg/exec) with a simple `doPost` for testing:

```js
const doPost = (request = {}) => {
  const { postData: { contents, type } = {} } = request;
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(contents);
};
```

This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/KKZjMaq?editors=1010) sample shows how requests with HTMX fail while `fetch` and `XHRHttpRequest` are successful.

Some things I've learned:

- The `OPTIONS` header sent in a preflight results in a 405 error, aborting the request entirely. You can mimic this by sending an `OPTIONS` request via Postman (or similar) to the web app URL.
- The error doesn't include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, which is what shows as the failure reason in the console.
- HTMX sends non-standard headers, [which trigger preflight requests in modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). However, you can strip all headers out, which should bypass the preflight, but doesn't. [See this related discussion in the repo](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/779).

In this kind of situation, what is the best method for debugging? I'm not really sure what else to try to get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with HTMX, that requires modification of its source code. The source of the problem is that HTMX adds some event listeners to `xhr.upload` [that makes the browsers mark the request as "not simple"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests), triggering the CORS preflight request:

> If the request is made using an XMLHttpRequest object, no event listeners are registered on the object returned by the XMLHttpRequest.upload property used in the request; that is, given an XMLHttpRequest instance xhr, no code has called xhr.upload.addEventListener() to add an event listener to monitor the upload

The specific part of [HTMX source code](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/blob/6a7df0a8c11ea7f9051546d2c6e63f0cf3933344/src/htmx.js#L2766):

```
forEach(['loadstart', 'loadend', 'progress', 'abort'], function(eventName) {
    forEach([xhr, xhr.upload], function (target) {
        target.addEventListener(eventName, function(event){
            triggerEvent(elt, "htmx:xhr:" + eventName, {
                lengthComputable:event.lengthComputable,
                loaded:event.loaded,
                total:event.total
            });
        })
    });
});
```

Sadly, the `addEventListener` uses anonymous functions, so there's no way to remove them with `removeEventListener` AFAIK.

But if you are willing to use a custom HTMX script in your app until the authors fix this issue (e.g. add ability to prevent event listener creation on `xhr.upload`), just remove the `xhr.upload` from the list in the second row:

```
forEach(['loadstart', 'loadend', 'progress', 'abort'], function(eventName) {
    forEach([xhr], function (target) {
        target.addEventListener(eventName, function(event){
            triggerEvent(elt, "htmx:xhr:" + eventName, {
                lengthComputable:event.lengthComputable,
                loaded:event.loaded,
                total:event.total
            });
        })
    });
});
```

With this modification your original suggestion of removing non-standard HTMX-specific headers via `evt.detail.headers = []` will work, since now this request becomes "simple", so no more CORS preflight is made by the browsers.

Note: the modification may break the HTMX file upload, I did not test it.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you.

Comment: @Brian would you be able to clarify exactly what you did on the client side to get this working? Thanks.